# Not sure if I need a mutex or not

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads, mutex

I'm new to concurrent programming so be nice. I have a basic sequential program (which is for homework) and I'm attempting to turn it into a multithreaded program. I'm not sure if I need a lock for my second shared variable. The threads should modify my variable but never read them. The only time count should be read is after the loop which spawns all of my threads has finished distributing keys.

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 50000

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h> 

void binary_search(int *array, int key, int min, int max); 

int count = 0; // count of intersections
int l_array[ARRAYSIZE * 2]; //array to check for intersection

int main(void)
{
    int r_array[ARRAYSIZE]; //array of keys
    int ix = 0;

    struct timeval start, stop;
    double elapsed;

    for(ix = 0; ix < ARRAYSIZE; ix++)
    {
        r_array[ix] = ix;
    }
    for(ix = 0; ix < ARRAYSIZE * 2; ix++)
    {
        l_array[ix] = ix + 500;
    }

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    for(ix = 0; ix < ARRAYSIZE; ix++)
    {
        //this is where I will spawn off separate threads
        binary_search(l_array, r_array[ix], 0, ARRAYSIZE * 2);
    }

    //wait for all threads to finish computation, then proceed.

    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", count);

    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    elapsed = ((stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000+(stop.tv_usec-start.tv_usec))/1000000.0;
    printf("time taken is %f seconds\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}

void binary_search(int *array, int key, int min, int max)
{
    int mid = 0;
    if (max < min) return;
    else
    {
      mid = (min + max) / 2;
      if (array[mid] > key) return binary_search(array, key, min, mid - 1);
      else if (array[mid] < key) return binary_search(array, key, mid + 1, max);
      else 
      {
          //this is where I'm not sure if I need a lock or not
          count++;
          return;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: read -> increment -> store.  Non-atomic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the code as you've written it does both read and modify the variable. If you were to look at the machine code that gets generated for a line like

```
count++
```

you'd see that it consists of something like

```
fetch count into register
increment register
store count
```

So yes, you should use a mutex there. (And even if you could get away without doing so, why not take the chance to practice?)

Answer (score 6):

As you suspect, `count++;` requires synchronization. This is actually not something you should try to "get away with" not doing. Sooner or later a second thread will read count after the first thread reads it but before it increments it. Then you will miss a count. It is impossible to predict how often it will happen. It could happen once in a blue moon or thousands of times a second.

Answer (score 4):

If  you simply want accurate increments to `count` across multiple threads, these types of single-value updates are precisely what the interlocked memory-barrier functions are for.

For this I would use :[__sync_add_and_fetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) if you're using gcc. There a host of different interlocked operations you can do, most of them platform-specific, so check your documentation. For updating counters like this, however, they can save a heap-ton of hassle. Other samples include [InterlockedIncrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) under Windows, [OSAtomicIncrement32](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/OSAtomicIncrement32.3.html) on OS X, etc.

Comment: Or, you could use the `atomic_fetch_add` generic function from the new C11 `stdatomic.h`. :-)

Comment: @R.. dammit i really need to get up to speed with the C11/C++11 specs. I feel like technology is leaving me in the dust. SO busy at work hardly any time to sleep much less study. I'll check it out. thanks.

Comment: Basically it's just a new standardized name for the gcc generic function.

Comment: That's really cool, I didn't know about pre-built atomic operations.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins they definitely come in handy, especially when doing something like what you need in your post.